# Want to pass Filename as argument to AppleScript

Tags: filenames, argv

I struggle greatly with AppleScript.  I cannot even write a simple script that takes a filename and opens it in the appropriate app.

I tried this:

```
on run argv
    tell application "MindNode"
        open file (item 1 of argv)
    end tell
end run
```

This gives me:

```
osascript test.scpt dysfunctions.mindnode
missing value
```

Very grateful for assistance.